# Fill EditTextPreference programmatically on edit

Tags: android, edittextpreference

Below is a part of my code that sets the phone number automatically.

```
  @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Preference connectionPref = findPreference(key);
        if (connectionPref != null) {
            connectionPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
        }

        //get phone number automatically
        if (key.equals("pref_phone_number")) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            }

            TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) MainActivity.getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
            connectionPref.setSummary(mPhoneNumber);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(key, mPhoneNumber);
            editor.commit();
        }

    }
```

Would it be possible to have the `EditTextPreference` programmatically filled with `mPhoneNumber` when it's clicked on and the edit window opens? I want to give the user the ability to edit their number, which right now they can not.

Comment: Replace Preference by EditTextPreference

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this,

```
EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)PreferenceManager.findPreference("edit");
EditText prefEditText = pref.getEditText();
prefEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
prefEditText.setSingleLine(true);
prefEditText.setText("yourText");
```

Comment: This wouldn't be in the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method right? which method should I put it in?